# Cookie Not Sent Over SSL

Tags: ssl, cookies, spring-boot, tomcat8, jhipster

We want to send cookies cookies over SSL.We are using Apache tomcat as server and technologies we are using are Spring boot, angulerJS application is developed using Jhipster.

Below is our application configuration

tomcat 8 context.xml

```
<Context useHttpOnly="true">
```

Server.xml

```
    <Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
maxThreads="200" keystoreType="jks" scheme="https" Server=" " Secure="true" 
SSLEnabled="true" keystoreFile="/home/Keystore/keystore.jks"
keystorePass="keypass" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
            TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
            SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA" useServerCipherSuitesOrder="true"/>
```

But in response header we are getting following.

[image]

Please help me whats wrong in my configuration

Comment: The `useHttpOnly` is only for the session cookie not for other cookies. So nothing is wrong with your configuration it works as it should, your understanding is/was wrong.

Comment: Thanks  @M. Deinum for your reply, is there any configuration for other cookies to send them over SSL

Comment: Assuming you are using a recent Spring Security version for the CSFR support configure it accordingly. However by default it doesn't expose the csfr token as a cookie so yu probably implemented your own filter to do so... (Or JHipster has one, modify/configure it for `httpOnly` cookies).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @M.Deinum for your guidance to directed me in correct direction.

changed following line in filter.

```
cookie.setHttpOnly(false);
        cookie.setSecure(true);
```

Thanks & Regards
Mahesh